# Are there differently normalized forms of the dual of the Turan-Kubilius innequality?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am reading Elliot's fabulous book "Probabilistic Number Theory I", and they present that upon dualizing a variant of the Turan-Kubilius inequality one obtains that

$$\sum_{p\leq x}p \left|\sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ n\equiv{0} \mathrm{mod}{p}}}a_n-p^{-1}\sum_{n\leq x}a_n\right|^2 \leq 16x\sum_{n\leq x}|a_n|^2$$

There are many inequalities which state essentially this same thing with only the bound $p<x$ changing, like for instance

$$\sum_{p\leq x^{1/2}}p \left|\sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ n\equiv{0} \mathrm{mod}{p}}}a_n-p^{-1}\sum_{n\leq x}a_n\right|^2 \leq (x+36x(\log x)^{-1})\sum_{n\leq x}|a_n|^2$$

> Here is my question: Is there any known inequality of the type
> $$\sum_{p\leq B(x)}p^2 \left|\sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ n\equiv{0} \mathrm{mod}{p}}}a_n-p^{-1}\sum_{n\leq x}a_n\right|^2 \leq F(x)\sum_{n\leq x}|a_n|^2$$
> or
> $$\sum_{p\leq B(x)}p \left|\sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ n\equiv{0} \mathrm{mod}{p}}}a_n-p^{-1}\sum_{n\leq x}a_n\right| \leq F(x)\sum_{n\leq x}|a_n|^2$$
> where the power of $p$ and the power of the term $\left|\sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ n\equiv{0} \mathrm{mod}{p}}}a_n-p^{-1}\sum_{n\leq x}a_n\right|$ are the same?

The result that I want to show is that

$$\lim_{Q\to\infty}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{Q}\sum_{p\leq Q}\left|\frac{p}{x}\sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ n\equiv{0} \mathrm{mod}{p}}}a_n-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}a_n\right|=0$$

where the decay as $Q\to\infty$ is at a rate determined by $\sum_{n\leq x}|a_n|^2$, or more specifically at a rate determined by $|a_n|<1$. I can prove that

$$\lim_{Q\to\infty}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{Q}\sum_{p\leq Q}\left|\frac{p}{x}\sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ n\equiv{0} \mathrm{mod}{p}}}a_n-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}a_n\right|=0$$

does indeed hold for any fixed choice of $a_n$ but it is the global rate I am struggling with.